# How to get character code at < 126

Tags: c#, javascript, arrays

I'm simply creating a 256 byte array in my server-side application and then sending it to client.

**C#:**

```
byte[] arr = new byte[256];
for (int i = 0; i < 256;i++ )
{
    arr[i] = (byte)i;
}
```

and then I want to get all character codes (exactly, byte codes from characters) in client-side with JavaScript.

**JavaScript:**

```
for(var i = 0;i<data.length;i++) {
    console.log(data.charCodeAt(i));
}
```

The characters after `126`, `charCodeAt(...)` returns `65536`.

Exactly I want to know how can I get this character codes after `126`?

Comment: Are you sure you can send raw binary data over ajax?

Comment: Exactly no, but in some situations I need to do that. You mean this is a problem with browser or ajax request?

Comment: This is a problem since raw binary data can create corrupt json/xml/csv data. If I would do it I would probably do it using base64.

Comment: use base64 encoding at server and decoding at client.

Comment: @MarcusJohansson Thanks for response. You said I can't send raw binary data, so, this is the browsers limitation?

Comment: No, this is a limitation of most human readable data containers. Since csv uses comma, raw data may contain a comma and cause a new field to begin when there is actually data left in the current field. Also, since UTF-8 for example is not described using a fixed size for each char, I imagine the length of the data sent could differ from the data received on the client. Just guessing though, not an expert.

Answer (score 1):

There are some very good tips on how to parse binary data using charCodeAt in this blog post:
http://fhtr.blogspot.com/2009/12/3d-models-and-parsing-binary-data-with.html

You can also use jDataView if you want to easily read binary data in JavaScript:
http://blog.vjeux.com/2011/javascript/jdataview-read-binary-file.html

Comment: That's all is good but my problem is about transferring this `bytes` over HTTP not how to use it or work with them. I've worked with `TypedArray` also but it works when you have your raw bytes. I think it's just posible to transfer bytes over HTTP with `WebSocket`. Thanks again friend, +1 :)

Comment: @AfshinMehrabani You have to set the charset to x-user-defined as it's mentioned in the first link.

Comment: I didn't see that, sorry. Ok let me check it.